# How do I properly terminate a MonoTouch application?

Tags: xamarin.ios, terminate

I am using the following code, but even after I call it, my app is still in the iOS task manager (double-click on the Home button).

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.PerformSelector(
     new MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector("terminateWithSuccess"), null, 0f);
```

When I delete the app from the task manager (hold on app in the task manager for 2-seconds then press the red minus sign), it disappears from the task manager as it should.

If I terminate it using the code above, why is it still in the task manager?  How do I programmatically kill it hard so that it disappears from the task manager?

Comment: An application's icon being present in the "task manager" does not necessarily mean it is even running.  Applications are added to this list as they are launched, and will remain there until the user removes them.  If the user hits the minus, it will kill the app if it is running.  The OS might also kill your app on it's own if a low memory condition is reached, this is just the app lifecycle of iOS.  Even so, you should not kill your application yourself as @Jason mentions, Apple will reject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forcing the app to close (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5137) through the iOS interface wont remove it from the 'task manager'. The 'task manager' really shows a list of recent apps.

Terminating an app programmatically wont remove it from the recent apps list.

Answer (score 3):

this is a no-no according to Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html).  Doing this may cause your app to get rejected

> Don’t Quit Programmatically
>
> Never quit an iOS application programmatically because people tend to
>   interpret this as a crash. However, if external circumstances prevent
>   your application from functioning as intended, you need to tell your
>   users about the situation and explain what they can do about it.
>   Depending on how severe the application malfunction is, you have two
>   choices.
>
> Display an attractive screen that describes the problem and suggests a
>   correction. A screen provides feedback that reassures users that
>   there’s nothing wrong with your application. It puts users in control,
>   letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and
>   continue using your application or press the Home button and open a
>   different application
>
> If only some of your application's features are not working, display
>   either a screen or an alert when people activate the feature. Display
>   the alert only when people try to access the feature that isn’t
>   functioning.